# markov chain with ant in a triangle

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

An ant walks from vertex to vertex of a triangle in a clockwise direction with probability: 
$\begin{cases}
P = \frac{1}{2} \text{ if it's at vertex 1} \\
P = \frac{3}{4} \text{ if it's at vertex 2} \\
P = 1 \text{ if it's at vertex 3}
\end{cases}$

What is the PTM of this Markov chain?

I think it has 3 states (the vertices) but the way I'm understanding the probabilities show that rows don't sum to 1 which is most likely incorrect.

For example, I set the transition probability from state $1$ to state $2$ as $\frac{1}{4}$ because that's the probability it takes the ant to travel there?

$\hspace{7.75cm}$`1`$\hspace{2mm}$ `2`$\hspace{2mm}$ `3`

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to consider the alternative cases. It goes to the clockwise state with probability $p$ and counterclockwise with probability $1-p$.

$\hspace{7cm}$`1`$\hspace{9mm}$ `2`$\hspace{9mm}$ `3`

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1-\frac{1}{2} \\
1-\frac{3}{4} & 0 & \frac{3}{4} \\
1 & 1-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: but doesnt the condition that the ant walks clockwise cancel this possibility?

Comment: "in a clockwise direction with probability: ..."

Comment: @MoronicHero It means that if the ant is a vertex 1 it moves to vertex 2 or 3 with equal probability ($1/2$). If it is at vertex 2 it moves to vertex 3 with probability $3/4$ otherwise it moves to vertex 1. If it is at vertex 3 it certainly moves to vertex 1.

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks for the alternative explanation

Comment: Note @MoronicHero that generally speakig, when you are in a state, the sum of outbound probabilities (taking into account possible transition to the same state and other states) should be one.

Comment: @msm thanks for the note

Comment: You're welcome @MoronicHero